# How to set any visible window of other programs to be on top?

Tags: c#, windows

What is needed to grab the handle of a visible window and set it to remain on top?

For example being able to set the onTop property of some other application ( let's say notepad) to be on top.

Is there a simple way to do this with Win 7 or 8 ? not really looking for low level trickery with windows API's if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a window Topmost given a window handle via:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

// Call this way:
SetWindowPos(theWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

The method to get the appropriate window handle varies based on the application.  You likely can get it via [Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx), though sometimes it requires using `EnumWindows` in the Windows API if it's not a "main window".

Using the above, for Notepad, for example, you could do:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
SetWindowPos(processes.First().MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

HWND_TOPMOST will put the window on to permanently (until some other window is tagged as topmost) but if you want the window to simply pop to the front try:

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP     = new IntPtr(0);